# Using worker/background processes in node.js vs async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku

I want to know if there is any benefit in passing off db or other async calls to a worker process or processes. Specifically I'm using heroku and postgres. I've read up a good bit on node.js and how to structure your server so that the event loop isn't blocked and that smart architecture doesn't leave incoming requests hanging longer than 300ms or so.

Say I have the following:

```
 app.get('/getsomeresults/:query', function(request, response){
    var foo = request.params.query;
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
            client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE cat=$1", [foo], 
            function(err, result){
            //do some stuff with result.rows that may take 1000ms
            response.json({some:data})
            });
    });
 });
```

Being that postgresql is async by nature is there any real benefit to creating a worker process to handle the processing of the results set from the initial db call?

Answer (score 0):

You don't gain any benefit for running async functions in another process because the real work (running the SQL query) is already running in another process (postgres). Basically, the async/event-oriented design pattern is a lightweight process manager for things that run outside your process.

However, I noticed in your comment that the processing in the callback function does indeed take up a lot of CPU time (if that's really the case). That portion of code does benefit from being run in another process - it frees the main process to accept incoming requests.

There are two ways to structure such code. Either run the async function in a separate process (so that the callback doesn't block) or just run the relevant portion of the callback as a function in a separate process.

Comment: Hmm, so the callback //do some stuff will block the main process?

Comment: As long as the `do stuff` part is not async then yes, it will block. The event loop is just a fancy abstraction over a `while(){switch(){}}` loop (in other words, a state machine)

Comment: Ah, seems I was incorrect in assuming that everything from the initial client.query including callback was async.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `client.query` from a separate process won't give you a real benefit here, as sending queries to the server is already an asynchronous operation in node-pg. However, the real problem is the long execution time your callback function. The callback runs synchronously in the main event loop and blocks other operations, so it would be a good idea to make this non-blocking.

**Option 1: Fork a child process**

Creating a new process every time the callback is executed is no good idea, since each Node.js process needs its own environment, which is time consuming to set up. Instead it would be better to create multiple server processes when the server is started and let them handle requests concurrently.

**Option 2: Use Node.js clusters**

Luckily Node.js offers the `cluster` interface to achieve exactly this. Clusters give you the ability to handle multiple worker processes from one master process. It even supports connection pooling, so you can simply create a HTTP server in each child process an the incoming requests will be distributed among them automatically (node-pg supports pooling as well).

The cluster solution is also nice, because you don't have to change a lot in your code for that. Just write the master process code and start your existing code as workers.

The [official documentation on Node.js clusters](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) explains all aspects if clusters very well, so I won't go into details here. Just a short example for a possible master code:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var os = require("os");
var http = require("http");

if (cluster.isMaster)
    master();
else
    worker();

function master() {
    console.info("MASTER "+process.pid+" starting workers");
    //Create a worker for each CPU core
    var numWorkers = os.cpus().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
        cluster.fork();
}

function worker() {
    //Put your existing code here
    console.info("WORKER "+process.pid+" starting http server");
    var httpd = http.createServer();
    //...
}
```

**Option 3: Split the result processing**

I assume that the reason for the long execution time of the callback function is that you have to process a lot of result rows and that there is no chance to process the results in a faster way.

In that case it might also be a good idea to split the processing into several chunks using `process.nextTick()`. The chunks will run synchronously in several event-loop frames, but other operations (like event-handlers) can be executed between these chunks. Here's a rough (and untested) scetch how the code could look like:

```
function(err, result) {
    var s, i;
    s = 0;
    processChunk();

    // process 100 rows in one frame
    function processChunk() {
        i = s;
        s += 100;
        while (i<result.rows.length && i<s) {
            //do some stuff with result.rows[i]
            i++;
        }
        if (i<result.rows.length)
            process.nextTick(processChunk);
        else
            //go on (send the response)
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think node-pg offers some way to receive a query result not as a whole, but split into several chunks. This would simplify the code a lot, so it might be an idea to search into that direction...

**Final conclusion**

I would use option 2 in the first place and option 3 additionally, if new requests still have to wait too long.